# Convergence in probability of exponentially distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following problem:
Let $(X_{k})_{k\geq1}$ be a sequence of independent, exponentially distributed random variables with $\lambda=1$. Show that for all $\alpha<1$, we have $n^{\alpha}\cdot\left(\min_{k\leq n}X_{k}\right)\overset{P}{\rightarrow}0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I tried using the law of large numbers. I think this might be the correct idea, but I do not manage to get to the wanted result.
Could someone give me a hint or a tip which leads me in the right direction? Please do not post a solution.

Thanks in advance and have a great day

Comment: Just looking at the desired claim, it seems like it is enough (and perphaps the intended proof) to show that the probability that the minimum is less than or equal to $1/n$ goes to 1 as $n \to \infty$, or at least is less than or equal to $1/n^{1-\epsilon}$ for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ with probability approaching $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Start by showing that the distribution of $\min_{k\le n}X_k$ is exponential with parameter $n\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $P(\min_{k\le n} X_k > t) = P(X_1>t)^n$.

Hence you can derive even the almost sure convergence, not only in probability.